# Allow owner to read and create files, but not change or delete (mounted ntfs partition)

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, fstab

### I would like to:

- *mount my ntfs partition (fstab or mount)*
- *configure what is necessary...*

#### then what I expect:

- rm "file_that_existed_before_I_mounted_the_partition" # fails, deletion is not allowed for files that existed before I mounted the drive.
- echo hello2 > "file_that_existed_before_I_mounted_the_partition" # fails, can't overwrite file that existed before I mounted the drive
- echo hello > test # succeeds, because test doesn't exist, and creation is allowed
- echo hello >> test # whatever, the file was created by me after mount
- echo hello2 > test # whatever, the file was created by me after mount
- cat test # succeeds, because reads are allowed
- rm test # whatever, delete or not, because I created this file after I mounted this partition.

I have tried to follow the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222738/allow-owner-to-create-read-files-but-not-modify-or-delete

It suggests that for a dir like:

```
$ ls -ld dir
drwxr-xr-t 2 stephane stephane 4096 Aug 12 12:28 dir/
```

Could be done like:

```
$sudo bindfs -u root -p u=rwD,g=r,dg=rwx,o=rD dir dir
```

but it did not work.

- I was able to read and create files (good)
- But I was also able to delete files that were already there (bad)
- When using `rm`command, it warned me, saying that file was protected.
- However, using `unlink` (or any program that uses unlink syscall),
  the file is simply deleted.

I noticed that I can't set the `t`for the directory in question
(it is a NTFS mounted partition).
I tried using

```
sudo chmod o+t /mounted/dir
```

and

```
sudo chmod o+t /binded/dir
```

But both resulted in "Operation not permitted".

I tried it also *before* mounting, which did set the `t`,
but then it was reset when mounted.

If anyone knows why is that, please share.
I would prefer to configure this using only `fstab`.

### EDIT

Found a solution.
I basically read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209009/set-sticky-bit-by-default-for-new-directories-via-acl
and adapted to my situation.
I used ntfs-3g with `acl` enabled.
Later I will answer my question properly.

Comment: Are you saying a user could create a file, and not subsequently modify, overwrite or delete that same file?

Comment: @DrMoishe Just added a note to explain that.

Comment: "After a user has created a file, for me it does not matter if he can delete it or not. Only that he cannot delete files that were already there." Needs more explanation... user creates a file, **it's there on the server**.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits. Now the question should be clear.

Comment: OK so it looks like you are mounting a NTFS files system from Unix/Linux environment.  They do not support all of the same rights. Either way when you mount the partition/folder, this changes nothing. The rights are unmodified.  If you give someone the right to create/modify/delete (basically all the same right) then they can do that for all files. You could change the inherited right of the folder so the users have alright, then change the rights of the files you want unmodified, but I am not aware of how to dynamically limit rights to files created before you mount something.

Comment: This could get very confusing as you can set rights at two points, but this is not something I would advise. If you can read what I have written and come back with any further comments, we should be able to help more.  It might also be helpful if you could provide a little more on the NTFS partition, where and on what is this hosted, because this is where I think it is safest to set the permissions.